# influxdb high volume of data - api optimization

Tags: mqtt, influxdb, telegraf

I'm writing about 500k samples per second into influxdb using telegraf and MQTT.
Although CPU and memory are in low utilization, influx cannot store the data at this speed.

Data is generated locally, so I don't have network problems.
HD doesn't have latency problems, and could store much more data than this.

I send the data in plain text, and I think that it oculd be a bottleneck in converting the string into float.

Does anyone have had similar problems?

Thank you

I didn't find anything on the documentation, but I hope it's possibile to send float data directly in binary format.

Comment: Please click [edit] and show representative code for injecting data - it is unclear if you are using `curl` or `python` or `C` or how you are batching data and so on...